# Can the sample size $n$ be in either factor when doing Fisher–Neyman factorization?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

I was looking for a sufficient statistic for a random sample of this distribution when a question came to mind.

$$
f_X(x)=\frac{\left(\theta-1\right)^{x-1}}{\theta^x}, \ \ \ 
x=1,2,...\ and \ \ \theta >1
$$

This is my approach.

$$
L(\theta) = 
\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\left(\theta -1\right)^{x_i-1}}{\theta^{x_i}} =
\frac{(\theta -1)\strut^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i)-n}}
     {\theta\strut^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}}                                 =
h\left(\textstyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n}} x_i;\theta \right)k(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)
$$

where $k(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=1$.

I think that this means $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$. However, I understand that the function $h$ can't have any of the data in it (any $x_i$'s) except in the form of the statistic, which in this case is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$. But is $h$ allowed to have the sample size $n$ in it like in this example? The sample size could be viewed as a function of the data (e.g. $len(x_1, x_2,..., x_n) =n$), so maybe $n$ shouldn't be in $h$. However, sufficiency has to do with the amount of information that is provided about the parameter $\theta$ so I'm thinking that since $n$ provides no information about $\theta$, $n$ can be in either factor, $h$ or $k$, when doing Fisher–Neyman factorization. Is this correct? If I'm on the right track, can someone provide a better explanation?

Comment: Indeed $n$ can appear in both factors implicitly.  In other words, the factorization is actually a family of factorizations $f_n(x\mid\theta)=k_n(x)h_n(t_n(x);\theta)$ for every $n$, but decorating with $n$ everywhere just gets in the way of the idea.